# Terrain's Edges Matching

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, unity3d-terrain

I load some terrains from my asset bundle, but their edges are not matched together.
I recognize when I edit the terrain in Unity Editor, the problem is solved because the terrains are in the same terrain group (see it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b6uRVc__0ECxXgQr4pCtll6ahEgfpSB2/view?usp=sharing)).
So my question is: Can I do it runtime by code? If yes, please tell me how! Many Thanks!

[image]

P/S: I know the function TerrainData.SetHeights() and I can match edges of two terrains with this function, but I don't want to do it so manually.